# Accord du participe passé

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, en

J'ai lu dans une chronique de Pascal Pia la phrase suivante :

> [Baudelaire] tint cependant à commenter l’œuvre de Dupont avec **autant de chaleur qu’il en aurait eu**, s’il avait eu à s’acquitter de cette tâche à l’époque où il admirait le chansonnier éclairant dans ses couplets « les horizons divers de la souffrance et du travail humain ».

Le participe passé d'avoir ne devrait-il pas s'accorder avec *chaleur* et présenter la forme *eue* ?

Answer (score 1):

Non: le COD est bien "en", qui remplace en effet "la chaleur". MAIS le participe passé ne s'accorde jamais avec le COD qui précède si ce COD est "en".
C'est une exception à la règle générale de l'accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire avoir.

Cf règle [ici](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-precede-de-en-184.php).

Answer (score -2):

Oui, vous avez raison: le COD est ici "en", mis pour "chaleur", donc féminin. Le COD étant placé avant le verbe avoir, le participe passé doit s'accorder, donc il fallait écrire "eue" et non "eu".

Comment: J'aimerais savoir qui a dévalorisé ma réponse, et pourquoi? Cela m'intéresserait.

Comment: Parce que la réponse est incorrecte: il n'y a pas d'accord avec le COD si ce COD est "en".

Comment: J'ai cherché cette éventualité dans "Le Bon Usage" et elle ne s'y trouve pas.

Comment: A la réflexion, honte sur moi! en faisant tourner des phrases "en" dans ma tête, je me rends compte qu'effectivement il n'y a pas d'accord. un moment d'égarement...